# Batch Normalization in 4D data over features instead of channels (PyTorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement batch normalization in my CNN via `nn.BatchNorm2d`. My data is of size `(N, C, H, W)` where `N` is the batch size, `C` is the number of channels, and `HxW` is the image size. Now in 1d batch normalization, the output is normalized *for each feature* over the entire batch; if `x^i_j` is the `j^th` feature of the output of the `i^th` sample in the batch, then all `x^i_j` for a fixed `j` are normalized (i.e. picking a single feature, this leads to samples from a standard Gaussian over the entire batch). Now with 2d batch normalization, it seems to be a little different: the output is normalized *for each channel* over the entire batch, i.e. if we pick one channel, then *all features of this channel over the entire batch* are normalized. (More explicitly, if `x^i_j_c` is the `j^th` feature of the `i^th` sample in the batch, in channel `c`, then we normalize over all `x^i_j_c` *for all `i` and `j`*, for fixed `c`. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what the standard 2d batch normalization seems to be working like.) This has been leading to very poor results for me. I feel like it might be beneficial to perform the batch normalization in a fashion more similar to the 1d case, i.e. for fixed `c` and fixed `j`, we normalize over all `i`. So my first question is, is this something that's also done, or does it not make sense for a specific reason? And: is there an easy way to achieve this sort of batch normalization in PyTorch for 2d data? (Without having to reshape everything into 1d data, then perform 1d batch normalization and then reshaping everything back.)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider writing a custom batch normalization layer. To do so, you  need subclass the `torch.nn.Module` class and implement its `forward` method. The `forward` method will contain the required processing.

Here is some biolerplate code:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class MyBatchNormalizationLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Define any attributes here

    def forward(self, x):
        # Perform the required processing on x and return it
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then the easiest way to do this would probably be to reshape the data into 1d data, perform 1d batch normalization and shape it back within the forward function. Which is what I had thought of already; I was just wondering if there is a direct built-in pytorch tool for this (the fact that there isn't tells me that this kind of batch normalization doesn't make sense? Although intuitively, to me, it does.)